Show all selectizegroupUI options but grey out?
Is it possible to show all selectizegroupUI options but grey out the unavailable selections based off of what it already selected?
For example, when selecting a Manufacturer, show all other options but grey out if unavailable (and vice versa).
Could one combined the solution below with selectizegroupUI?
Grey out a selectInput choice after clicking a checkboxInput - R Shiny

library(tidyverse)
library(tidylog)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(datamods)
library(reactable)
library(data.table)
library(janitor)
library(readxl)

data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      select_group_ui(
        id = "my-filters",
        params = list(
          manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", label = "Manufacturer:"),
          model = list(inputId = "model", label = "Model:"),
          trans = list(inputId = "trans", label = "Trans:"),
          class = list(inputId = "class", label = "Class:")
        ),
        vs_args = list(disableSelectAll = FALSE), 
        inline = FALSE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      reactableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  res_mod <- select_group_server(
    id = "my-filters",
    data = reactive(mpg),
    vars = reactive(c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class"))
  )
  
  output$table <- renderReactable(reactable(res_mod()))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

On a related note, select_group_ui doesn't seem to work/acknowledge NAs if the column name has a space in it - is it possible to overcome this?
mpg <- mpg %>%
   mutate(model = if_else(drv == "f" | drv == "r", NA, model)) %>% 
  rename("Model with space" = "model")


Your code is not reproducible, provide a minimal, reproducible example, in particular define all needed libraries, define select_group_ui and so on and test your code in a fresh R session on whether it works before you post it here.

Updated with the libraries.
